# Why doesn't using the @ mark always highlight users?

Tags: support

When I am commenting on other posts, I use @ to ping other users. Sometimes when I type @ and the user's name, it auto-generates their full name if I type in the first few letters. But other times it does not, and I have to type the full name. I don't know if they are actually being pinged.

Answer (score 3):

See also: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/309033)

If you're commenting on a question or an answer post, the poster is automatically notified and the @ method is redundant.

If a user (including the question/answer poster) comments on the post. You will be able to use the @ method to ping the user and the username will be auto-generated.

You will be unable to use the @ method to ping users that have not left a comment on a post.

If you're posting in chat, the @ method works on those that have recently left a message in chat.

You can also reply to a specific message by clicking on the option tab on the left of the message and selecting "reply to this message" Or use the shortcut on the right of the message.

[image]

Comment: This comment is an example. I typed @ and began to type your username but it did not generate it automatically. Is that because you are pinged automatically? If user “12345” comments under this, and I type @12 will it automatically generate 12345 as it does at other times?

Comment: @kandy ^ そそ・・　＾＾

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/309033